# Intuition for number of ways of distributing $n$ objects in $r$ groups

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations

Suppose I have $n$ objects(non-identical) and I want to distribute them in $r$ groups.Let's say $n=r=10$ .The solution given is $10^{10}$. I cannot understand this result at all. Well I know if I try to make cases it seems summing up all the $\prod \binom{n}{r}$ will give $(1+9)^{10}$ but in the book it's done as- ways for distributing objects for each box is $n$ and since there are $r$ boxes then total ways are $n^r$. Can someone help me understand this method.

Comment: The answer $10^{10}$ is valid only if the groups are also distinct.

Comment: and if you can put an object in more than one group.

Comment: By "distinct", I meant distinguishable, or labelled

Answer (score 1):

The $r$ groups are *labelled* (though not explicitly stated)

Now each object has $r$ choices for group,

and we just apply the multiplication principle to get $r\cdot r \cdot r.. = r^n$

Comment: What do you mean by "not distinct" groups? Is it such that one object can be placed in two or more groups? Doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: By distinct, I mean labelled. Changing terminology in the answer.

Comment: Okay I got what you mean. For example if grouping (in terms of cardinality of each group) $(2,3,1)$ and $(1,3,2)$ are the same then indeed the answer does not work.